# Sync Offline Database with External Database Windows Phone 7

Tags: sql-server, database, windows-phone-7, synchronization

I have a wp7 app that uses the local database implemented with linq. I have an external MS-SQL (2008 R2) server. Both databases have the same schema.

I would like to know how to do the following:

1. Download information from the MS-SQL to the Database into the local DB of the phone. (Can I use some data-binding technique - I have found no links that do this)
2. If Changes made on the phone (add new record, edit existing record) how can I push changes back to server.
3. If changes are made to server then push to phone (I know I can use an observer pattern here)

I should also note that the client app is not used always-on access to the internet.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no magic here.

You will need to create functionality to get updates from the server (probably meaning you need some kind of timestamp on each record, saying when it was last changed so you can query it).

You will need to create the functionality to upload data and update the database on the server (and potentially handle conflicts).

I would either use ODATA to communicate with the server, or plain old WCF/JSON service.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the [Sync Framework Toolkit](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Sync-Framework-Toolkit-4dc10f0e)